# Class for joined tables

Tags: c#, class

I have two tables that I need to join

```
employee
-id
-name
-department_id
```

and

```
department
-id
-department_name
```

How can I handle the joined data in a single class? Should I create properties for all the data for each table?

e.g

```
class employeerecord
{
    private int id {get; set;}
    private string name {get; set;}
    private int department_id {get; set;}
    private string department_name {get; set;}
}
```

Right now, I'm using a datatable for viewing joined tables.

Comment: Best approach would be to have a single property `Department Department`

Comment: @DeanAngco I think this question is too broad and primarly opinion-based. I can think right away for at least 3 different ways to design this and it depends on you overall design  and how you want to use this class.

Comment: Not related to your question, but recommend you use CamelCase for your naming convention in C#. Your code looks a bit java-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole design should include all entities you have in your database, i.e. there's departament table, there should be corresponding class. Same applies to employee table. You should have following classes:

```
class Employee
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int department_id {get; set;}
    public Departament department {get; set;}
}

class Departament
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    //public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

When loading data, you should wirte join query, to populate both: `Employee` instance and `Departament` instance.

You can uncomment commented line, if you'd like to have list of employees in particular departament.

Answer (score 1):

This solely depends on what you want to do with this classes. You can go either way.

If you want to display a single employee and that employee can only belong to one department, then nothing speaks against a flat model:

```
class employeerecord
{
    private int id{get;set};
    private string name{get;set;}
    private int department_id{get;set;}
    private string department_name{get;set;}
}
```

If an employee can be a member of multiple Departments, you are better off storing the departments in a collection:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int id{get;set};
    public string name{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Deparment> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

The same goes for departments. A department will most likely consist of multiple employees:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public int id{get;set};
    public string name {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And there is no reason, why you can't do all at once and use the classes depending on your specific use case.

Comment: I just wanted to get the value of the foreign key so that I can display it on  form,. Is it okay to have a class for employees basic info such as name,address,contact number, and another class for employee_asset with properties of employee_id,employee_name,item_id,item_name,department_id,department_name